How can I detect any kind of user activity on the page, including screen readers and assistive technologies?
I am building a learning React application hosted on a finicky system that, if the session is not properly closed, loses all progress and makes them start over. I don't have control over that system, but I figured ways to intercept closing the browser or refreshing the page and closing the session before leaving the page. What I have a harder time is preventing a timeout of the session with some assistive technologies that don't let the browser know that a key was pressed (like NVDA's virtual cursor) or that the virtual cursor moved.
I have tried capturing focus, blur, key press, up/down, scroll, asked ChatGPT and Claude.ai but when I use a screen reader, the inactivity countdown happily continues while I interact with the non-interactive elements of the page. Interactive elements are easy to intercept, but paragraphs and text don't trigger a thing. I certainly don't want to annoy the user with a popup while they are reading content, so how can I know if they are actively using the page?
Just to be clear, I don't want to detect if a user is using assistive technology, only to capture any interaction with the page, including AT.
